# Struggling with trans in a input placeholder

Tags: django, translation

Here is the HTML part

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={% trans "First Name" %} id="cf-fn" name="cf-fn" required="">
</div>
```

Instead of getting 'First Name', I got just 'First'. Here is a photo:

[image]

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never used django yet but I think it's an HTML problem.

Try setting the placeholder value between double quotes:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{% trans "First Name" %}" id="cf-fn" name="cf-fn" required="">
</div>
```

Without the double quotes the browser is getting just the first word as the placeholder value and the second word is used as another attribute (*Name*) with no value.